# Assign a value from getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, css, getboundingclientrect

I was trying this code from W3Schools and modified it to assign the resulted LEFT value to another element (DIV)

[getBoundingClientRect example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GUJV2JOEUX8V)

Nothing happens even if the left value 8 is correctly recovered ! Any idea on how i am trying this assigning wrong !
Thanks

Comment: Are you rmembering to add the 'px' unit also what positioning has the other element got? Please put your code into your question otherwise any answer is just a guess.

Comment: @AHaworth i have no code it's just a w3school course i am following and i edited their code in their editor, the link is in the description for the code, thanks

Comment: @AHaworth thanks buddy put your comment as an answer so i can accept it, it was the unit PX that's a real newbie error out there

Comment: Please make sure all relevant code is available here on Stack Overflow. See [ask], where it says, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly assign CSS you need to pass a valid value [more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Left) to it. So it needs to have e.g. `"px"` or `"%"` at it.

In short, it would work like that:

```
document.getElementById("aaa").style.left = x + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add: `+ "px"`

Therefore change the following line:

```js
document.getElementById("aaa").style.left = x;
```

to:

```js
document.getElementById("aaa").style.left = x + "px";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).